# db2 access on different systems

Tags: db2

Hi 
I am currently using db2 for some project work.The issue seems to be that we are a team of 4 and all of are working on the same database(not concurrently though).So ideally one of us create a backup of the database on one system and pass it others. We are able to connect to the database on other system,but not query it.I guess it is a issue with granting access. How do i solve this issue?

Comment: Do you mean you could connect all to the same database via network and not select? Or you could connect to locally restored database and could not select? What is the concrete error message?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by backing up the database and pass the backup to others. If you want the same database to be restored on other systems you can use redirected restore. 
You can do this very easily on the current db with the command:
db2 restore database  taken at  redirect generate script

If you have problems with access it could be you are restoring the database on different systems with different users. Db2 primarily uses local (system) users for db access - apart from the instance owner/admin sysadmin users.